# Kill android toast?

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I have a button and on button click toast appears, if the user clicks on button several times and go to previous activity or even close the aplication toast is still visible,

How to finish or cancel the toast when user goes to any other activity or how to prevent generation of toast?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter correct goal!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Dou you really want the user to be able to show several toasts? Maybe you can prevent that cause, by saving that the toast already appeared.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re how i can do that? i am mew to this tech

Comment: Well, the plain and easy way would be to set a boolean variable (which for example is located in your activity) to true, when the button is clicked and the toast appeared. e.g if(toastShown == false){{showToast();toastShown=true;} Therefore, you only show the toast if the variable is false and set it to true afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

try this `cancel()` `Toast` by using `handler`

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 toast.cancel(); 
 }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel individual `Toasts` by calling `cancel()` on the `Toast` object. AFAIK, there is no way for you to cancel all outstanding `Toasts`, though.

When calling **finish()** on an activity,  the method **onDestroy()** is executed this method can do things like:

1. Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
2. Close any cursors the activity was managing.
3. Close any open search dialog

Also, **onDestroy()** isn't a destructor. It doesn't actually destroy the object. It's just a method that's called based on a certain state. So your instance is still alive and very well* after the superclass's onDestroy() runs and returns.Android keeps processes around in case the user wants to restart the app, this makes the startup phase faster. The process will not be doing anything and if memory needs to be reclaimed, the process will be killed.

So make object of `Toast` in your class and call `cancel()` in `onDestroy()` method

```
Class YourClassActivity extends Activity{

      private static Toast toast;

public void initToast(){
    if (toast != null)
        toast.cancel();
    toast =  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setText("Enter correct goal!");
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      if (toast != null)
        toast.cancel();
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if (toast != null)
        toast.cancel();
}
}
```

Call `initToast()` method inside your `Button` click event.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast`s are [unrelated to their context](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/07/24/the-making-of-prixing-4-activity-tied-notifications/).

You can use an alternative (AppMsg, Crouton or the new SnackBar), or keep a reference to your `Toast` and `cancel()` it in your `Activity.onPause()` let's say.