# Kill the Toast Message

Tags: java, android-toast

In my App there are 13 buttons with different toasts.
When i click the other button the toast is not stopping destroying properly , this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.gg);
        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gg);
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast  = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Good Game", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                mp1.start();
                toast.cancel();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by  the toast is not stopping destroying properly??

Comment: I mean i click Button one then toast appears , now i click the second button but it displays the message after completion of first toast.

Comment: i want to kill the first toast immediatly when i press second toast.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel individual `Toasts` by calling `cancel()` on the `Toast` object

```
 if (toast != null)
 {
   toast.cancel();
 }
```

You may refer [Kill android toast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042825/kill-android-toast)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a duration to your toast, that is the way toast self-destruct.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

You can find many many examples on toast implementation.

[Android Developer Website - Toast Example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: The OP already have that `Toast toast  = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Good Game", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`